# Update sql based on the email subject

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am developing a ticketing system which has feature of incoming and outgoing email. I am having hard time in fixing the update record based on the subject of email. let say the subject of email is "EIM-1234-567: Test Mail only" and the ticketid table contains id like "EIM-1234-567 / EIM-1231-435 / EIM-5463-123". Please let me know what is wrong with my query. Your suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
$newupdate = "UPDATE dbticket SET data_update = '$datetime', indicator = '$indicator', readstat = '$readstat' WHERE ticketid LIKE '%$subject%'";
mysqli_query($conn, $newupdate);
```

Comment: Don't munge query strings with values.  Learn to use parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your fast response. Sorry I am new in web developing and my knowledge are just based on self studying. Could you please enlighten me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: explode on colon, use the first part for the match

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp - in reference to what @Gordon Linoff said, you can read this article to better prepare your query (for security against SQL injection, but read more on this subject to better understand security)

Comment: This is what I've done, but it seems conflict on other query.

$subj = mb_substr($subject, 0, 16);
$subre = str_replace("RE: ","",$subj );
$subfw = str_replace("FW: ","",$subre);

$newupdatetkt = "UPDATE dbticket SET data_update = '$datetime', indicator = '$indicator', readstat = '$readstat' WHERE ticketid LIKE '%$subfw%'";
mysqli_query($conn, $newupdatetkt);

Answer (score -1):

Seems it is working now.
I've used mysqli_multi_query(connection,query).
Thank you all.